UPI intent apps are not showing on inappwebview in flutter while calling a payment gateway url. if i open the same url on normal browser it work fine
I have a razorpay integration on my flutter application. The existing implementation uses flutter inappwebview to hit the payment gateway url. Issue is when the url is being called from inappwebview on flutter application it is not displaying the upi apps on intent like paytm & gpay. When i open the same url on chrome browser or any other browser on phone or desktop it works fine. Any suggestions what can be done to fix this issue on inappwebview in flutter. Using below plugin.
flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.1
I tried alternate methods like opening the same url on chrome browser. It works fine there. But due to existing implementation i am stuck with using inappwebview to access the payment gateway. It is not allowing upi intent apps to open.

change user agent to:

"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148
Safari/604.1"

if this do not works then go to google chrome and search "my user agent", copy and paste the same user agent, and all set.
